# JS alert if inputted date 2 <= date 1

Tags: javascript, date, alert

I have a form where a visitor can make a lodging reservation with an arrival date and departure date. If they click on an input field a calendar pops up for them to select a date. How can I add a popup JS alert if the departure date is <= the arrival date? My code is as follows:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/CalendarPopup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(getCalendarStyles());</script>
...
</head
    <script type="text/javascript" id="jsArrive">
var now = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(now);
yesterday.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);
var calArrive = new CalendarPopup("divArrive");
</script>
<b>Arrive:</b>
<input type="text" name="dateArrive" value="" size="15" onClick="calArrive.select(document.forms[0].dateArrive,'dateArrive','d/M/yyyy'); return false;" title="calArrive.select(document.forms[0].dateArrive,'dateArrive','d/M/yyyy'); return false;" id="dateArrive" />
</p>
<div id="divArrive" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;background-color:white;layer-background-color:white;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" id="jsDepart">
var now = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(now);
yesterday.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);
var calDepart = new CalendarPopup("divDepart");
</script>
<b>Depart:</b>
<input type="text" name="dateDepart" value="" size="15" onClick="calDepart.select(document.forms[0].dateDepart,'dateDepart','d/M/yyyy'); return false;" title="calDepart.select(document.forms[0].dateDepart,'dateDepart','d/M/yyyy'); return false;" id="dateDepart" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit"  />
</p>
<div id="divDepart" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;background-color:white;layer-background-color:white;"></div>
```

Comment: are `calArrive` and `calDepart` date objects?

Comment: @JaromandaX—see `var calArrive = new CalendarPopup("divArrive");`

Comment: d'oh ... new ... I'm an idiot

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple  as comparing the two dates, like so:

```
if (departureDate <= arrivalDate) {
   alert ("You must make sure your departure is before your arrival!);
}
```

I suggest you run the above if statement when the user has entered there arrival date. So you'd use an onChange event on each of the inputs incase they go back and change there departure date!

Comment: Thanks, James111. But where and how to place it? I've tried it in various different places but it won't pop up an alert.

Comment: @BunyipBluegum Remember that javascript runs line by line and if it comes across an alert it will stop executing until it has been dismissed. Put all your code in the same file and include it!